# Using PowerShell, can I copy one file from my local system to many remote computers in parallel?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, workflow, file-copying

As the title suggests, I cant seem to get either workflows or foreach-object -Parallel to work.

Here is one attempt:

```
$Computers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Inputfiles\computers.txt'
$SourcePath = 'C:\Temp\Inputfiles\VMTools\Setup64.exe'

$Job = $Computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  Copy-Item -Path $using:SourcePath -Destination "\\$_\C$\Temp\" -Force
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} -ThrottleLimit 5 -AsJob

$Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

I tried variations of the above, but cant get it to work.

Here is the error I was getting on the above:

```
>  .\Copy-FileToRemote.ps1
ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Temp\ITScript\Workflow\Copy-FileToRemote.ps1:4 char:21
+ $Job = $Computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Wait-Job : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Job'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Temp\ITScript\Workflow\Copy-FileToRemote.ps1:9 char:8
+ $Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
+        ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Wait-Job], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WaitJobCommand
```

Comment: What happened with each of your attempts? Did you receive errors? Unexpected behavior? If so: share the error messages in full, and describe the unexpected behavior you're observing. We can't see your screen :)

Comment: `ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.` is because `-Parallel` was implemented in powershell 7. As an alternative you could use a PSSession assuming powershell remoting is enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.4#example-5-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**:

- **Windows PowerShell *workflows*** were introduced in v3, but never really took off. Given that they're [no longer available in *PowerShell (Core) v6+*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/), where all future development effort will go, they should be considered ***obsolete***.
- In regular PowerShell sessions, the **`-Parallel` parameter** of the **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** cmdlet **requires [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**.

---

To get the benefits of *parallel* processing, use the following approach:

- Create a remoting session *explicitly*, targeting *all* target computers, using [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession).
- Use that session with [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item)'s `-ToSession` parameter to copy the source file to *all* target computers.

```bash
$session =
  New-PSSession -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\temp\InputFiles\computers.txt)

Copy-Item -ToSession $session C:\temp\InputFiles\vmtools\Setup64.exe -Destination C:\temp\
```

Note that, with a `-ToSession` argument, the `-Destination` parameter is implicitly treated as *target machine-local*.

Also, the requirement is that the target directory on each machine, `C:\temp`, *must already exist*.

Comment: Great, I'll re-write like this! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

File Deployment Script

```
$computers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\InputFiles\computers.txt'

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $scriptblock1 = {
        param($sourcepath, $destpath, $computer)
        Copy-Item -Path 'c:\temp\InputFiles\vmtools\Setup64.exe' -Destination "\\$computer\c$\temp\" -Recurse -Force 
    }

    # Run the script block on each remote computer in parallel
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock1 -ArgumentList $sourcepath, 'C:\temp', $computer
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you handling any errors or failures that might occur?

Comment: Note that your code targets the computers _sequentially_, not in parallel.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, I realized that after I posted.